React Client request to FastAPI backend returning 405 Method not allowed
I'm using FastAPI to receive form submissions from a React based login page. However, I am receiving a 405 error upon submitting a request from my frontend:

However, when testing out json inputs on the FastAPI endpoint ui, it works fine:

Below is my frontend page with the form and on submit async funcs:
page.tsx
export default function Goal(){
    const [username, setUsername] = useState(""); 
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(""); 
   
    
    async function onSubmit(event : FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
      
        event.preventDefault()
        
        const formData = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        
        try{
          const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend_testing', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData) // Send as JSON
            });
            // const responseData = await response.json();
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
        
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <div className={inter.className} style={{
                        color: '#4C4C4C',
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: '700',
                        wordWrap: 'break-word',
                        display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        height: '100vh' 
                    }}>
            <VStack spacing='24px'>
                <div>
                <p>Login Page</p>
                </div>

                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <p>Username</p>
                    <Input onChange={(e) => {
                        setUsername(e.target.value);
                    }}/>
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <Input onChange={(e) => {
                        setPassword(e.target.value);
                    }}/>
                    <Button 
                        colorScheme='blue'
                        type = "submit"
                    >
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </VStack>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

And below is my relevant python code:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Annotated

app = FastAPI()
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

class UserInfo(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str

....

@app.post("/frontend_testing")
async def create_user(req: UserInfo, db: db_dependency):
    
    print(f"Username: {req.username}")
    print(f"Password: {req.password}") 

I've double checked my endpoint and my client request, and they seem to be properly setup for a post-request. Any help would be appreciated

You need to enable the CORS middleware to allow your frontend to make a cross-site request to the API: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/  - The OPTIONS request is the first part of this request where your browser validates that it is allowed to make requests to your backend.

Does this answer your question?
